# Android EditText: How do I get rid of the graphical glitches?

Tags: android, edit

When I create an EditText in a standard-activity using the following setContentView with the following View:

```
public final class TestView extends LinearLayout {

    public TestView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        EditText text2 = new EditText(context);
        text2.setText("Test");
        this.addView(text2);
    }

}
```

I get graphical glitches like the following when editing it:

[image: Graphical glitches]

How can I get rid of those? Is this an Android Bug?

Comment: I only have ONE EditText. Which sits in the upper left corner. The second text that is displayed is what was before in the box before I edited it. I guess it's an android-bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set any parameters to the EditText. Try setting the parameters for it and check,

```
EditText text2 = new EditText(context);
        text2.setText("Test");      
        text2 .setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                1f));
        text2 .setWidth(100);       
        text2 .setMaxLines(1);
        this.addView(text2);
```

Comment: Android sets default-parameters if none are passed to addView(). It shouldn't produce glitches like that anyway.

Comment: Your code works, but the EditText goes across the whole line now. I have to check whether it works in my final layout as well. I guess the graphic-error lies in the multiline-box, which I don't need anyway. Thanks.